# Search, count duplicated strings and add for each numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates

I have a script that is searching for duplicated text strings in an array and changing the colors.

```
function checkDuplicates() {
    var values = new Array();
    var $input = $('input[type=\'text\']');
    var error = 0;
    $input.each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('double-error');
        var that = this;
        if (that.value!='') {
            values[that.value] = 0;
            $('input[type=\'text\']').each(function() {
                if (this.value == that.value) {
                    values[that.value]++;
                    }
                });
            } //endif
        });

    $input.each(function(key) {
        if (values[this.value]>1) {
            error++;
            $(this).addClass('double-error');
            }
        });

    return (error <= 0); //returns false or true
    }

<style type="text/css">
    .double-error {
        color:red;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
</style>
```

**This is working fine.**

---

However, I need to count duplicated strings and add keep track of whether they are the first occurence of that word, the second occurence of that word, etc.

For example:

Given `john, john, peter, doe, peter, john`, the result would be `john-1, john-2, peter-1, doe, peter-2, john-3`.

---

This is what I currently have:

```
function eliminateDuplicates() {
    var values = new Array();
    var $input = $('input[type=\'text\']');
    var error = 0;

    $input.each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('double-error');
        var that = this;
        if (that.value!='') {
            values[that.value] = 0;
            $('input[type=\'text\']').each(function() {
                if (this.value == that.value) {
                    values[that.value]++;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $input.each(function(key) {
        if (values[this.value]>1) {
            error++;
            myArray = values[this.value];
            for (var i = 0; i < myArray; i++) {
                $(this).parent()
                .find('input[type=\'text\']')
                .val(this.value + '-' + i);
                } 
            }
        });

    return error <= 0; //return error > 0 ? false : true;
    }
```

But I got this result:

> john-0-1-2, john-0-1-2, peter-0-1, doe, peter-0-1, john-0-1-2

What's wrong?

---

I make some modification:

```
function eliminateDuplicates() {
        var values = new Array();
    var $input = $('input[type=\'text\']');
    var error = 0;
    $input.each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('double-error');
        var that = this;
        if (that.value!='') {
            values[that.value] = 0;
            $('input[type=\'text\']').each(function() {
                if (this.value == that.value) {
                    values[that.value]++;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $input.each(function(key) {
        if (values[this.value]>1) {
            var name=this.value;
            var names = values[this.value];
                values[this.value]++;
            for (var i = 0; i < names; i++){
        $(this).parent().find('input[type=\'text\']').val(name + '-' + i);
            }


        }

    });
checkDoubles();
    return error <= 0; //return error > 0 ? false : true;
}
```

now I getting counts in sequence but not from 1.
for example if I have 4 duplicated names (Peter) i getting:

> Peter-3, Peter-4, Peter-5, Peter-6.
>   but I need
>   Peter-1, Peter-2, Peter-3, Peter-4.
>   what wrong?

Comment: I really think if you made a fiddle, we could help you faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you're looking for something like this:**

```
function eliminateDuplicates() {

    var repeats = {};
    var error = false;

    //cache inputs
    var $inputs = $("input[type='text']");

    //loop through inputs and update repeats
    for (i = 0; i < $inputs.length; ++i) {
        //cache current element
        var cur = $inputs[i];

        //remove class
        $(cur).removeClass("double-error");

        //get text of this element
        var text = $(cur).val();

        //no text -- continue
        if (text === "") {
            continue;
            }
        //first time we've came across this value -- intialize it's counter to 1
        if ((text in repeats) === false) {
            repeats[text] = 1;
            }
        //repeat offender. Increment its counter.
        else {
            repeats[text] = repeats[text] + 1;
            }

        //update the the value for this one
        $(cur).val(text + "-" + repeats[text]);
        }

    return error; // always returns false since I'm not sure
                  // when it's supposed to return true.
    }
```

---

**PS:** I didn't understand when `error` was supposed to be `true`, so it's always `false`. Nevertheless, this should be enough to get you going.

**PPS:** [Plunker here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/fLnHcFzl5Mof0KbNcBYi?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this also not working. I can't  it adapt.

Comment: @KęstutisBanišauskas: I'm not sure what "I can't it adapt" means. Would you please explain/clarify?

Comment: this mean that script not working. I try to make some changes modification but not working at all...

Comment: @KęstutisBanišauskas: Are you getting errors? Could you add the html? What's happening?

Comment: No erros. I have checked with Free Java Script editor. And no erros on the browser. Nothing happening when calling this function.

Comment: I try this 'code' $input.each(function(key) {
        if (values[this.value]>1) {
            error++;
var name=this.value;

myArray = values[this.value];
            for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){

$(this).parent().find('input[type=\'text\']').val(name + '-' + i);
}

});
'code' But seems length not working. Also no action when calling function. Without length I got all quantity duplicated strings but I need add sequence numbers to each duplicated.

Comment: @KęstutisBanišauskas: So you're not even **using** the code I gave you??

Comment: I told you your code not working at all hmm I don't know why. Sorry.

Comment: @KęstutisBanišauskas: Did you call the function? Like: `eliminateDuplicates()`.

Comment: @KęstutisBanišauskas: Oh, and if you really want this fixed, adding the relevant html would be a big help.

Comment: @ Jefré N. It is little bit complicated recreate simple html equal my sitauation, because i'm calling data from sql using php. Strings repeating regarding records in sql. To recreate I need to make new piece "eliminate duplicated" javascript. html table with some inputs and so on.

Comment: @KęstutisBanišauskas: I finally decided to quit beating around the bush, so I made a plunker and solved the problem. My code example was updated and so it now works! :) Tell me if you have any questions or comments. (Don't forget to call `eliminateDuplicates` like `eliminateDuplicates();`!)

Comment: @ Jefré N. You are genius!!!  Thank's a lot. Working fine. I have voted your answer, but my reputation are the low to public show my voting.

Comment: @KęstutisBanišauskas: Terrific -- I'm glad it's working. Thanks for upvoting. If you don't mind, I would appreciate if you *accepted* it by clicking that checkmark. It will give me a reputation bonus, give you a reputation bonus, and let others know that this answer was solved. :) Anyways, happy coding! :)

Comment: So script working fine if I have up to hundred entries in database. But if I have several thousands of records, browser is freezing. Firefox crashing at all. How to prevent browser freezing and crashing and add for example some loading line o some clock pointer? Can you suggest something?

Comment: @KęstutisBanišauskas: Maybe. However, I think it would be better for you to ask another question or ask it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ Jefre N. I asked new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552440/prevent-browser-freezing-and-crashing-for-long-time-calculation