# Prevent browser freezing and crashing for long time calculation

Tags: javascript, freeze, web-worker

I need check in my database names who are duplicated and change this name to avoid duplicates. I using  script suggested by @Jefré N.

```
function eliminateDuplicates() {

    var repeats = {};
    var error = false;

    //cache inputs
    var $inputs = $("input[type='text']");

    //loop through inputs and update repeats
    for (i = 0; i < $inputs.length; ++i) {
        //cache current element
        var cur = $inputs[i];

        //remove class
        $(cur).removeClass("double-error");

        //get text of this element
        var text = $(cur).val();

        //no text -- continue
        if (text === "") {
            continue;
            }
        //first time we've came across this value -- intialize it's counter to 1
        if ((text in repeats) === false) {
            repeats[text] = 1;
            }
        //repeat offender. Increment its counter.
        else {
            repeats[text] = repeats[text] + 1;
            }

        //update the the value for this one
        $(cur).val(text + "-" + repeats[text]);
        }

    return error; // always returns false since I'm not sure
                  // when it's supposed to return true.
    }
```

So script working fine, but if I have up to hundred entries.  But if I have several thousands of records, browser is freezing. Firefox crashing at all. How to prevent browser freezing and crashing by adding  for example some loading line o some clock pointer? Maybe I need to use some setTimeout() function or something else. Please help to prevent this browser freezing and crashing problem.

I tried this:

```
function processLargeArrayAsync(array, fn, maxTimePerChunk, context) {
    context = context || window;
    maxTimePerChunk = maxTimePerChunk || 200;
    var index = 0;

    function now() {
        return new Date().getTime();
    }

    function doChunk() {
        var startTime = now();
        while (index < array.length && (now() - startTime) <= maxTimePerChunk) {
            // callback called with args (value, index, array)
            fn.call(context, array[index], index, array);
            ++index;
        }
        if (index < array.length) {
            // set Timeout for async iteration
            setTimeout(doChunk, 1);
        }
    }    
    doChunk();    
}
```

-

```
processLargeArrayAsync(veryLargeArray, myCallback);
```

No success. Chrome freezing, IE11 explorer also, Firefox crashing. Whats wrong?
My records appear in the HTML table.

Some people advise to use a web worker. Maybe someone here has the practice and have a functioning example?

Comment: `setTImeout` would work, what is your question?  Have you tried it yet?  Post what you have tried, preferably at jsfiddle.net and post a link.

Comment: Use webworkers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Ok thanks for suggestion. Newer tried this. Maybe some have good working example?

Comment: Greetings @KęstutisBanišauskas! I have a few questions. 1. Why does this need done client side? 2. Are you still accessing the values from `<input>`s? If not, how are you looping through the values you need?

Comment: @  Jefré N. Thank you, When page are loding all data retriving from database. Than all data are putting to the input field for further checking of duplicates and adding numbers with your script. So when records are up to hundred it is all ok. When records are thousands browser are freezing. And popup alerts. So I need some solution to prevent this. I think maybe webworker can help, but no experience here. And need to add some loading bar for this to know that backgrond process are running.

Comment: I found this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168604/Combining-jQuery-Deferred-with-the-HTML-Web-Worke  There is about  web worker. But I have no experience with javascript. So somebody can help me to solve my problem

Comment: I would like to point out that it doesn't appear like you've tried anything. Maybe you should show how you've tried to use webworkers.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most cumbersome part of your code is the DOM access: getting input values and updating them.

According to the [webworkers documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), webworkers have their limitations and one of them is DOM manipulation. So I'd discard that option.

In order to fix things, I'd do as follows:

1. Improve your `eliminateDuplicates` algorithm (make it faster).
2. Make `eliminateDuplicates` asynchronous: divide the set of elements in smaller ones and perform each calculation in a different event loop tick (setTimeout).

Here I present you a solution I've come up with. Hope it gives you some ideas and help you to solve your problem.

First, I tweaked a bit `eliminateDuplicates` (I called it `modifyDOM`)

```
function modifyDOM(elements, repeats) {
    var input, text, i = 0;
    for (; i < elements.length; i++) {
        input = elements[i];
        text = input.value;
        // Remove class.
        input.className = input.className.replace(/\bdouble-error\b/, '');
        if (text) {
            repeats[text] = ~~repeats[text] + 1;
            input.value = text + "-" + repeats[text];
        }
    }
}
```

I avoided using jQuery inside the main loop because its wrapper makes things slower and in your case it wasn't worth using it. These small changes improved performance in 100ms per 10.000 elements (give it or take).

I created two functions that use `modifyDOM`: one asynchronous and other synchronous.

```
function parseElementsNonBlocking(elements, maxChunkSize) {
    var repeats = {},
        nChunks = Math.floor(elements/maxChunkSize),
        i = 0,
        j = 1;

    //loop through inputs and update repeats
    for(; i < nChunks; i++, j++) {
        setTimeout(modifyDOM.bind(null, elements.slice(i, j*maxChunkSize), repeats), 0);
    }
    // Rest
    setTimeout(modifyDOM.bind(null, elements.slice(i), repeats), 0);
}

function parseElementsBlocking(elements) {
    var repeats = {};

    //loop through inputs and update repeats
    modifyDOM(elements, repeats);
}
```

Lastly and in order to test everything, a function that executes when the DOM is ready and creates 10.000 inputs. It then outputs how long it takes to run any of the above methods.

```
$(function () {
    var inputsDiv = $('#inputs'), i, time;
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        var val = i % 3 === 0 ? 'Mickey' : (i % 3 === 1 ? 'Mouse' : '');
        inputsDiv.append('<input type="text" class="double-error" name="FirstName" value="' + val + '">');
    }

    time = Date.now();
    //parseElementsBlocking($("input[type='text']"));
    parseElementsNonBlocking($("input[type='text']"), 100);
    console.log(Date.now() - time);
});
```

Here you have the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jxb69d6/) to test it all.

Comment: Hi, Thank's for the answer. Seems I missing something. I can get it to work. This function 'function modifyDOM(elements, repeats)' doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution using OODK-JS to calculate the sum of an array of 1.000.000 entries through webworkers.

This solution implements the producer/consumer design pattern using the SynchronizedQueue foundation class: the producer (main thread) generate a task for each chunk of the array and add it to queue. The consumer (webworker) take a task in the queue and execute it until no one left. Once all tasks are executed, the producer display the final result

```
// main.js (producer)
          OODK.config({
            'path': {
              'oodk': '../src',
              'workspace': 'workspace'
            }
          });

          OODK(function($, _){

            $.import('{oodk}/foundation/utility/Thread', '[util.concurrent]', '{workspace}/project/Task');

            // array helper class to handle arrays
            var ArrayHelper = $.class(function($, µ, _){

              $.static(function($, µ, _){

                // slice an array into chunks using chunkLength argument
                // as delimiter 
                $.public(function slice(arr, chunkLength){

                  return arr.reduce(function(arr, val, index){

                    var chunkIndex = Math.floor(index/chunkLength); 

                    if(!arr[chunkIndex]) {
                      arr[chunkIndex] = [];
                    }

                    arr[chunkIndex].push(val);

                    return arr;
                  }, []);
                });

                // generate an array of len argument length
                // containing random values 
                $.public(function random(len){

                  var arr = [];

                  for(var i =0; i<len; i++){
                    arr.push(Math.random()*10);
                  }

                  return arr;
                })
              });

            });

            // class to handle a pool of thread
            var ThreadPool = $.class(function($, µ, _){

              // number of threads to instantiate
              $.private('num');

              // queue to works with
              $.private('queue');

              $.public(function __initialize(num, queue){

                _.num = num;

                _.queue = queue;
              });

              // start the pool
              $.public(function start(){

                // bind listeners
                var threadListener= $.new(Producer);

                for(var i=0; i<_.num; i++){

                  // instantiate consumers
                  var consumer = $.new(OODK.foundation.util.Thread, "consumer.js");

                  $.on(consumer, 'thread.ready', threadListener);

                  consumer.start();
                }

                $.on(_.queue, 'synchronizedQueue.taskDone', threadListener);

              });

            });

            // Event Listener for the thread
            var Producer = $.implements(OODK.foundation.EventListener).class(function($, µ, _){

              // number of task done
              $.private('taskDone', 0);

              // final result
              $.private('finalResult', 0);

              $.private(function __processEvent(evt){

                if(evt.getType() === 'thread.ready'){

                  // the thread is ready, synchronize the queue with the current thread
                  queue.synchronize(evt.getTarget());

                }else if(evt.getType() == 'synchronizedQueue.taskDone'){
                  //message received from the consumer that it has performed a task

                  _.taskDone++;

                  var cqueue = evt.getTarget();

                  var chunkResult = evt.getData();

                  _.finalResult += chunkResult;

                  jQuery('#chunksDone').text(_.taskDone);

                  if(cqueue.getCapacity() == _.taskDone){

                    // once all tasks are performed display the final result
                    $.log('final sum is ' + _.finalResult);
                  }else{
                    // each time a chunk is calculated display the intermediate result 
                    $.log('intermediate result ' + _.finalResult);
                  }
                }
              });
            });

            // generate a large array of 1.000.000 random values
            var myHugeArray = ArrayHelper.self.random(1000000);

            // split this array into chunks of 2500 length
            var chunks = ArrayHelper.self.slice(myHugeArray, 25000);

            // instantiate a synchronized queue setted as size the number of chunks
            var queue = $.new(OODK.foundation.util.concurrent.SynchronizedQueue, chunks.length);

            // for each chunk create a task and add it to queue
            for(var i=0; i<chunks.length; i++){

              var chunk = chunks[i];

              // create a task for each chunk of the array
              var task = OODK.project.Task.self.factory(chunk);

              // and add it to the queue
              queue.put(task);
            }

            // instantiate a pool of 2 threads working on the given queue
            var threadPool = $.new(ThreadPool, 2, queue);

            // start the pool
            threadPool.start();

            $.log('calculate the sum of an array of 1.000.000 entries using 2 threads ...');
          });
```

The consumer (webworker)

```
//consumer.js

OODK.config({
  'path': {
    'oodk': '../src',
    'workspace': 'workspace'
  }
});

OODK(function($, _){

  // import the concurrent API package as well as the task class
  $.import('[util.concurrent]', '{workspace}/project/Task');

  // start the synchronizer
  OODK.foundation.util.concurrent.SynchronizedObject.self.start();

  // EventListener Class to handle synchronized queue events
  $.implements(OODK.foundation.EventListener).class(function Consumer($, µ, _){

    $.protected(function __processEvent(evt){

      if(evt.getType() == 'synchronizedQueue.ready'){
        //queue is synchronized

        var queue = evt.getTarget();

        // bind listener
        $.on(queue, 'synchronizedQueue.elementRetrieved', this);

        // take a task: get the heap of the stack and delete it
        queue.take();

      }else if(evt.getType() == 'synchronizedQueue.elementRetrieved'){

        // task is retrieved from the queue

        var task = evt.getData();

        var queue = evt.getTarget();

        // execute the task
        var result = task.execute();

        // notify the producer that the task is done
        queue.notify('synchronizedQueue.taskDone', result);

        if(queue.remainingElements()>0){
          // at least one task is still in the queue, take it

          queue.take();
        }

      }
    });
  });

  var threadListener = $.new(_.Consumer);

  // global listener for the synchronizedQueue.ready event 
  // triggered when the synchronzied queue is synchronized with this thread
  $.on('synchronizedQueue.ready', threadListener);

});
```

The task class to implement the custom logic

```
OODK('project', function($, _){

  $.public().implements(OODK.foundation.Serializable).class(function Task($, µ, _){

    // the array chunk to calculate
    $.private('chunk');

    $.public(function __initialize(chunk){
      _.chunk = chunk;
    });

    // calculate the sum of all entries of a chunk
    // implements the custom logic here
    $.public(function execute(){

      var result = 0;

      for(var i=0; i<_.chunk.length; i++){
        result += _.chunk[i];
      }

      return result;
    });

    $.static(function($, µ, _){

      $.public(function factory(chunk){

        var task = $.new($.ns.Task, chunk);

        return task;
      });
    });
  });

});
```